# WooCommerce Order Status (Autocomplete orders)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I am making a simple e-commerce website using WooCommerce plugin on Wordpress. I am using **Paypal** as my **payment gateway**. When user is purchasing product from my store and give payment successfully, WooCommerce should automatically change **order status** from **`'pending'`** to **`'completed'`**, but it is not changing **order status**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: till the time paypal does not approves your order, and you get a succesfull payment message that is not possible

Comment: and if then also, you want it to be done search for payment option in your directory, there you can set hardcoded

Comment: So, Do I have to change order status manually?

Answer (score 3):

**This is a snippet code** (that you can find in wooCommerce docs):

> ```
> /**
>  * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
>  */
> add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order');
> function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
>     if ( ! $order_id ) {
>         return;
>     }
>
>     $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
>     $order->update_status( 'completed' );
> }
> ```
>
> But this snippet does not work for "BACS", "Pay on delivery" and "Cheque" payment methods. It's ok for Paypal and Credit Card gateways payment methods.

There is also a wordpress (woocommerce) free plugin working with all payment methods except some others **Credit Card gateways payment methods**:

[**Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689563/3730754)

[**WooThemes - WooCommerce Autocomplete Orders**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/)

Regards