# How to autocomplete paid orders in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

Normally, WooCommerce should autocomplete orders for virtual products. But it doesn't and this is a real problem, even a BUG like.

So at this point you can find some helpful things (but not really convenient):

**1) A code snippet** *(that you can find in WooCommerce documentation)*:

```php
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
**/
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order');
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

As this doesn't work for "Bank wire" *(bacs)*, "Cash on delivery" *(cod)* and "Cheque" *(cheque)* payment methods, it will only work for Paypal, Credit Card gateways, and others payment methods.

**2) A plugin**: WooCommerce Autocomplete Orders

This plugin works for all payment methods, **but not for** other **Credit Card gateways payment methods**.

---

Using (as a base) the WooCommerce snippet in point 1, how can I implement conditional code based on WooCommerce payment methods?

I mean something like: if the payment methods aren't "Bank wire", "Cash on delivery" or "Cheque", then apply the snippet code (update status to "completed" for paid orders concerning virtual products).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**The most accurate, effective and lightweight solution** *(For WooCommerce 3 and above) - **2019***

This filter hook is located in:

- `WC_Order` Class [inside `payment_complete()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order.html#122) which is **used by all payment methods** when **a payment is required** in checkout.
- `WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT` Class [inside `update()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT.html#157).

As you can see, by default the **allowed paid order statuses** are "processing" and "completed".

> #### Explanations:
>
> 1. **Lightweight and effective:**
>
>    As it is a filter hook, `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status`  **is only triggered when an online payment is required** *(not for "cheque", "bacs" or "cod" payment methods)*. Here we just change the **allowed paid order statuses**.
>
>    So no need to add conditions for the payment gateways or anything else.
> 2. **Accurate** *(avoid multiple notifications)*:
>
>    This is the only way **to avoid sending 2 different customer notifications at the same time**: 
>    • One for "processing" orders status 
>    • And one for "completed" orders status.
>
> **So customer is only notified once on "completed" order status.**

Using the code below, will just **change the paid order status** *(that is set by the payment gateway for paid orders)* to "completed":

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 3 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    return 'completed';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

**Related:** [WooCommerce: autocomplete paid orders based on shipping method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303688/woocommerce-autocomplete-paid-orders-based-on-shipping-method/48306674#48306674)

---

**2018 - Improved version** *(For WooCommerce 3 and above)*

Based on Woocommerce official hook, I found a solution to this problem *(Works with WC 3+).

In Woocommerce for all other payment gateways others than `bacs` *(Bank Wire)*, `cheque` and `cod` *(Cash on delivery)*, **the paid order statuses are "processing" and "completed"**.

So I target "processing" order status for all payment gateways like Paypal or credit card payment, updating the order status to complete.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 20, 1 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;
    
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array( 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque', '' ) ) ) {
        return;
    } 
    // Autocomplete all others payment methods
    else {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

---

**Original answer** *(For all woocommerce versions)*:

The code:

```
/**
 * AUTO COMPLETE PAID ORDERS IN WOOCOMMERCE
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
    return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( ( 'bacs' == get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) ) || ( 'cod' == get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) ) || ( 'cheque' == get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) ) ) {
        return;
    } 
    // For paid Orders with all others payment methods (with paid status "processing")
    elseif( $order->get_status()  === 'processing' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

With the help of this post: [**How to check payment method on a WooCommerce order by id?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011837/how-to-check-payment-method-on-a-woocommerce-order-by-id)

with this : `get_post_meta( $order_id, '_payment_method', true );` from [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking)

"Bank wire" (bacs), "Cash on delivery" (cod) and "Cheque" (cheque) payment methods are ignored and keep their original order status.

*Updated the code for compatibility with WC 3.0+ (2017-06-10)*

Comment: 'woocommerce_thankyou ' hook is fired only when user is redirected to the woocommerce  'thank you' page... this might not happen (if for some reason the user decides not to press the paypal "return to merchant" link

Comment: @YairLevy I know…So where is the problem as in this case the order will not be paid…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the problem is that the order *will be paid* but the action will not be performed. To make it clear: user leaves the site on checkout (redirected to paypal etc.) make a payment, and than instead of clicking "return to merchant" button will close the browser or maybe go to the sites home page or whatever... as long as he will not visit the "thank you" page - the order will not be completed

Comment: @YairLevy If it does that, anyway woocommerce don't receive the payment response from Paypal or any other gateway… It need to send the customer back to the site to receive the response… Remember that this code is based on official woocommerce snippet code…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec this is indeed the official woocommerce snippet... but it has a caveat (as explained on previous comment). Paypal uses IPN (instant payment notification) to send the payment approval back to the site. when it happens it triggers the 'woocommerce_payment_complete' hook (which is the right hook to use in case you want to autocomplete your order)

Comment: Really you saved me.

Comment: for me this hook was called even if the payment did not go through or failed , and this result to complete failed payments , after some research i changed it to use  'woocommerce_payment_complete' because its called only when payment is complete and cover the issue that @LoicTheAztec mentions above

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes i see that , but the question in its title contain "Paid Orders" and in comment of your code , you have to add one more check to check the status to make sure its update , of mention that so anyone use this code know that the hook is triggered also for failed payments and convert the status from failed to complete ( not from process to complete ) ....

Comment: @MotazHomsi I have updated my answer, with the most effective and light way, that avoid multiple email notifications to the customer on Paid orders.

Comment: Great answer, but you should be clear that `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` is a filter hook, so needs to return something. Using `add_filter` makes this more explicit

Answer (score 6):

For me this hook was called even if the payment did not go through or failed, and this resulted to completed failed payments. After some research I changed it to use 'woocommerce_payment_complete' because it's called only when payment is complete and it covers the issue that @LoicTheAztec mentions above –

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 20, 1 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array( 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque', '' ) ) ) {
        return;
    // Updated status to "completed" for paid Orders with all others payment methods
    } else {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the simplest hook to modify order status when payment is completed is 'woocommerce_order_item_needs_processing' as this filter hook is meant to modify the target order status when payment completes.

This is what the final snippet will look alike:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_needs_processing', '__return_false',999);
```

It also compatible with the other plugins on sites.

Answer (score 0):

For me, on a testing system with PayPal Sandbox (WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin) [the LoicTheAztec solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689563/1354580) (2019 update) worked only when I added the `$order->update_status( 'completed' );` code line. The `return 'completed';` has not an effect in my case, I left it just because it's a filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', function( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    return 'completed';
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, in your answer you used `add_action` for  the `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter, is this ok?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for autocompletion of virtual orders (like courses, ebooks, downloadables etc), this might be useful.

```
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce virtual orders.
 * 
 * @param  int  $order_id The order ID to check
 * @return void
 */
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_virtual_orders( $order_id ) {

    // if there is no order id, exit
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array( 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque', '' ) ) ) {
        return;
    } 

    // get the order and its exit
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // if there are no items, exit
    if ( 0 >= count( $items ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // go through each item
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        // if it is a variation
        if ( '0' != $item['variation_id'] ) {

            // make a product based upon variation
            $product = new WC_Product( $item['variation_id'] );

        } else {

            // else make a product off of the product id
            $product = new WC_Product( $item['product_id'] );

        }

        // if the product isn't virtual, exit
        if ( ! $product->is_virtual() ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /*
     * If we made it this far, then all of our items are virual
     * We set the order to completed.
     */
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_virtual_orders' );
```

Adapted from https://gist.github.com/jessepearson/33f383bb3ea33069822817cfb1da4258