# Woocommerce - Webhook for Paypal and Bank Transfer

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce in Wordpress to sell online my software. Until now i've accepted only Paypal payment: when someone buy my software, i use Webhook with "  action.woocommerce_payment_complete" event to call a PHP page that creates the user access.

Now, i want to add the Bank Transfer payment. The problem is.. which event should i use? "woocommerce_payment_complete" is not called when someone do the order neither if i set the order as "on progress" or as "completed".

I would like to have a safe event to call when Paypal payment is complete or when i receive the bank transfer.

Thank you in advance!
Luca

Comment: Would be okay also if i find the way to programmatically call "woocommerce_payment_complete". Do anyone know how to do that?

Comment: You can do this by doing order status completed you need to do order status pending or add custom status.

Comment: When you say bank transfer do you mean BACS gateway? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597663/woocommerce-change-order-status-bacs-processing