# Change order status just after payment in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I need to change automatically an order status for completed after receiving payment, but only if the order status is "processing". I found that snippet, what makes orders status completed in every case, but my payments plugins after successful payment changes returns data and changes the order status for "processing". I would like to change it into "completed" after success and don't change it if the status isn't "processing". The main problem I met is I don't know how to get the received status order.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_order_status', 10, 2 );

function update_order_status( $order_id ) {
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   $order_status = $order->get_status();    
   if ('processing' == $order_status) {    
       $order->update_status( 'completed' );    
    }    
 //return $order_status;
}
```

---

Edit:

I figured it out already. Here's the code that works for me:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_order_status', 10, 1 );

function update_order_status( $order_id ) {
  if ( !$order_id ){
    return;
  }
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  if ( 'processing' == $order->status) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: I edited your post for code formatting and there is a typo. $oder_status

Comment: thank you, typo corrected too.

Answer (score 12):

> **Update 2** - 2019: Use [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563) (updated thread)
>
> So the right hook to use is `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter returning complete

---

**Update 1:** *Compatibility with WooCommerce version 3+*

I have changed the answer

Based on: [WooCommerce - Auto Complete paid virtual Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-virtual-orders-depending-on-payment-methods), you will be able to handle also all payment methods in conditionals:

```
// => not a filter (an action hook)
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) == 'bacs' || get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cod' || get_post_meta($order_id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cheque' ) {
        return;
     }
    // "completed" updated status for paid "processing" Orders (with all others payment methods)
    elseif ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really need to check the payment method, I got only one. But I had a new problem. I would like to change an order status not after accessing to the thank you page, but at the moment when the status is changed to 'processing'. Sometimes it happens that customer don't come back to my store, after the payment is accepted. Do u have any clue?

Answer (score 4):

The function `woocommerce_thankyou` is an action. You're required to use `add_action` function to hook into it. I would recommend changing the priority to `20` so that other plugins/code changes may be applied before `update_order_status`.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'update_order_status', 20);
```