# How to move order status to processing once payment has been done using paypal in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin to checkout orders using paypal method. But issue is that when payment is done then orders status should moved to processing but it is still showing pending. So how to do that. I want order status should move automatically to processing once payment is done using paypal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-virtual-orders-depending-on-payment-methods

Comment: I think it will not move order status pending to processing once payment is done, it is still stuck to pending

Comment: That is very strange…You can try this free plugin, it works mostly with paypal: [WooCommerce Autocomplete Orders](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/)

Comment: Plugin is not working, this is not a solution

Comment: So the problem could be coming from the settings of your payment method (in woocommerce or in paypal backend)… sorry for you… I can't do anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this below code in your function.php. This code change order status pending to processing once payment is completed.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'custom_update_order_status', 10, 2 );

function custom_update_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {

 return 'processing'; 

}
```

Comment: What is 10 and 2 here ?

Comment: @UpendraSharma `10` is the priority and `2` are the number of arguments or variables passed in this hook ( `$order_status` and `$order_id` )…

Comment: This is not updating the status yet, status is stuck to pending still ?