# Display a custom text on the Order Received Page just before order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am having difficulties customizing the text location on my Thankyou page/Order Received page. I got some custom text added, but I can't get it into the position I'd like.

See attached image. It is should up at the top, when I would like it under the photo in the "Order Details section)

```
/**
 * Custom text on the receipt page.
 */
function isa_order_received_text( $text, $order ) {
    $new = $text . ' If you do not see the download button(s) below, please refresh the page. Processing can take a few minutes.';
    return $new;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'isa_order_received_text', 10, 2 );
```

[image]

Comment: You are targeting the wrong filter/hook. Take a look at the [`order-details-item.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/templates/order/order-details-item.php) template for some more relevant options.

Answer (score 4):

To get this easily, you can use **`woocommerce_thankyou`** hook with the highest priority (1), this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_thankyou_text', 1, 0);
function custom_thankyou_text(){
    echo '<p class="thankyou-custom-text">If you do not see the download button(s) below, please refresh the page. Processing can take a few minutes.</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Code is tested and works.

Comment: How could we show this text only in case of selecting a specific payment method (wire transfer)?

Comment: @bobrock4 use something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39921252/3730754, replacing in the code 'cheque' with 'bacs' and using `echo '<p>Your message</p>';` instead of `$order->update_status( 'processing' );`