# Auto completed status for all existing processing orders in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am using on WooCommerce this little peace of code [**from this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689563/3730754) to autocomplete paid processing orders:

```
/**
 * AUTO COMPLETE PAID ORDERS IN WOOCOMMERCE
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 1 );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

  // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
  if ( ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'bacs' ) || ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cod' ) || ( get_post_meta($order->id, '_payment_method', true) == 'cheque' ) ) {
    return;
    } 
  // "completed" updated status for paid Orders with all others payment methods
    else {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I use a special payment gateway by SMS which API is bridged on 'cod' payment method, and the orders stay sometimes in on-hold status on this 'woocommerce_thankyou' hook.

So I will need to scan all the time the 'processing' orders to pass them in complete status. I have tried different things and hooks, but I cant get it work as expected.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this working you just need a little function that will scan all orders with a "processing" status on the 'init' hook, and that will update this status to "completed".

Here is that code:

```
function auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed(){
    // Get all current "processing" customer orders
    $processing_orders = wc_get_orders( $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
    ) );
    if(!empty($processing_orders))
        foreach($processing_orders as $order)
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed' );
```

This code is tested and works.

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

> **ADVICE & UPDATE**
>
> There is **a little bug** around **email notifications sent twice** that is **solved in here**:
> [Avoid repetitive emails notification on some auto completed orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41074461/avoid-repetitive-emails-notification-on-some-auto-completed-orders/41074630#41074630)

Comment: Great this piece of code do exactly what needed to achieve my demands. Thanks Loïc for your help, you saved my week-end ;)

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce virtual orders can be automatically marked as ‘completed’ after payment with a little bit of code added to a custom plugin, or your themes functions.php file. By default WooCommerce will mark virtual-downloadable orders as ‘completed’ after successful payment, which makes sense, but some store owners will want to be able to automatically mark even a virtual order as complete upon payment, for instance in the case of a site which takes donations where no further action is required. To do so, use the following code, which is based on the core virtual-downloadable completed order status:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'virtual_order_payment_complete_order_status', 10, 2 );

function virtual_order_payment_complete_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ) {
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

  if ( 'processing' == $order_status &&
       ( 'on-hold' == $order->status || 'pending' == $order->status || 'failed' == $order->status ) ) {

    $virtual_order = null;

    if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {

      foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        if ( 'line_item' == $item['type'] ) {

          $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );

          if ( ! $_product->is_virtual() ) {
            // once we've found one non-virtual product we know we're done, break out of the loop
            $virtual_order = false;
            break;
          } else {
            $virtual_order = true;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // virtual order, mark as completed
    if ( $virtual_order ) {
      return 'completed';
    }
  }

  // non-virtual order, return original status
  return $order_status;
}
```

**OR**

You can also use plugin for auto complete order

Here is the plugin URL : https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/screenshots/

Please let me know which is use full to you.

Thnaks.

Comment: Sorry HK but it doesn't worked for me, but the previous answer from Loïc does exactly what i'm looking for. Thanks any way :)

Comment: Anytime @NacerChikhi