# Testing Paypal payment processing

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm new at integrating PayPal into a woocommerce/WordPress site.  I'm testing the payment process.  When a customer purchases an item and checks out using the PayPal method, it shows up in WordPress as "processing".  How long does it take for the money to be received into the bank account and do I have to manually set the status to "completed" or does it do it automatically?

Thanks

Comment: The money is received automatically, but you have to manually set the status to "completed". Though there are plugins and code floating around to automatically mark orders as completed, especially relevant for virtual products that require no shipping.

Comment: See this related thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods

Comment: Please visit this link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/  OR https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/