# Adding selectbox to linked products tab in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have followed this instructions

[How to add more custom field in Linked Product of Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199599/how-to-add-more-custom-field-in-linked-product-of-woocommerce)

and this

[Add a custom multi-select field to admin product options settings in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172288/add-a-custom-multi-select-field-to-admin-product-options-settings-in-woocommerce)

to add a new selectbox to linked products and show selected products in frontend. Instead of something like are upsells with images/prices, I'm getting in both cases string "Array" on frontend:

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: no any hints or help?