# Woocommerce bulk change order status

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently having some issues with a WooCommerce site. There are thousands of old orders that are stuck on the status "processing". 
These orders have received payment and products have been shipped.

I would like to mark these orders as complete without sending completed order E-mails. I'd like to use the following SQL Query to achieve this.

```
update wp_posts set post_status = 'wc-completed' where post_type = 'shop_order' and post_status ='wc-processing' ;
```

Do I need to change other tables too or would this work?

Thanks

Edit: 
The above code worked perfectly for me.

Comment: You don't need to change other tables … this SQL query is perfect as it is… Then [**here is the way to auto complete paid orders**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689563/3730754) to avoid this happening again.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to update any other tables if you're only changing the order status. Note that you can also achieve this from within WordPress:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'wc-processing',
);

$orderList = get_posts($args);

foreach ($orderList as $orderPost) {
    $order = new WC_Order($orderPost->ID);
    $order->update_status('completed');
}
```

...although a direct SQL query will almost certainly be quicker in this circumstance.

Additionally, if you want to automatically convert orders to `completed` once they've been paid for, you can add the following filter:

```
function myWooAutoCompleteOrder($orderID) {

    //  Only continue if we have $orderID

    if (!$orderID) {
        return;
    }

    //  Get order

    $order = wc_get_order($orderID);

    //  Update order to completed status

    if ($order) {
        $order->update_status('completed');
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_thankyou', 'myWooAutoCompleteOrder');
```

Comment: Wouldn't doing it from within WordPress mean that order complete E-mails get sent?

Thanks

Comment: @user3215838 If you have the option for Completed emails checked, then yes; that first chunk of code will send the customers an email. You can always temporarily turn that off, but like I said: if you're doing this for a few thousand old orders, it probably makes the most sense to do it via SQL, and your SQL line should be fine.