# Set WooCommerce order status when order is created from processing to pending

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

When a woocommerce order is created the status of the order is "processing". I need to change the default order-status to "pending".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The default order status is set by the payment method or the payment gateway.

You could try to use this custom hooked function, **but it will not work** *(as this hook is fired before payment methods and payment gateways)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'changing_order_status_before_payment', 10, 3 );
function changing_order_status_before_payment( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $order->update_status( 'pending' );
}
```

Apparently each payment method (and payment gateways) are setting the order status (depending on the transaction response for payment gateways)…

> For Cash on delivery payment method, this can be tweaked using a dedicated filter hook, see: 
>   [Change Cash on delivery default order status to "On Hold" instead of "Processing" in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280800/plugin-of-woocommerce-sets-order-status-to-processing-instead-of-on-hold/53291919#53291919)

Now instead you can **update** the order status **using `woocommerce_thankyou`** hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status', 10, 1 );
function woocommerce_thankyou_change_order_status( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if( $order->get_status() == 'processing' )
        $order->update_status( 'pending' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

> **Note:** The hook `woocommerce_thankyou` is fired each time the order received page is loaded and need to be used with care for that reason... 
>   Now the function above **will update the order status only the first time**. If customer reload the page, the condition in the `IF` statement will not match anymore and nothing else will happen.

---

Related thread: [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, if the payment gateway that you use properly sets the order status using `WC_Order->payment_complete()`, you can use the `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` filter.

This is better than using `woocommerce_thankyou` hook since we are setting the order status immediately, rather than applying it after it has been already set.

```php
function h9dx3_override_order_status($status, $order_id, $order) {
  if ($status === 'processing') {
    $status = 'pending';
  }

  return $status;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'h9dx3_override_order_status', 10, 3);
```

Again, this will only work if the payment gateway uses the proper `payment_complete` wrapper method rather than setting status directly with `set_status`. You can just search the gateway code for 'payment_complete(' and 'set_status(' to see what it does.

If you develop a plugin for everyone, you will be better off with using `woocommerce_thankyou`, or you could use a combined approach and use `woocommerce_thankyou` as the fallback if the order status was not updated.

Answer (score 0):

The hook woocommerce_thankyou suffers from the problem that you can pay for an order and then close the browser or go somewhere else and therefore never click "Return to Merchant" (which is displayed after paying via paypal) to get to the thankyou page.  And then the code will never be executed.

Answer (score -4):

```
// Rename order status 'Processing' to 'Order Completed' in admin main view - different hook, different value than the other places
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_renaming_order_status' );
function wc_renaming_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) 
            $order_statuses['wc-processing'] = _x( 'Order Completed', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
```