# WooCommerce setting COD orders to On-Hold

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

**The problem:**
Need COD orders to be set to 'on-hold' instead of going straight to 'processing'.

**What I've tried:**
Using woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status hook to set the status but it doesn't seem to work and I haven't found anyone online that's managed to get it to work (within the last 3 years).

**Similar Stack Overflow Question:**
[Change COD default order status to "On Hold" instead of "Processing" in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280800/change-cod-default-order-status-to-on-hold-instead-of-processing-in-woocomme) 
This question has a solution that no-longer works. Yes, same question, but since then things have changed.

**What I've settled on (for now):**
For the moment, I've settled on using the following code that sets ALL orders to 'on-hold'. But this is very annoying.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'change_order_status', 10, 2 );
function change_order_status( $order_status, $order ) {
    return 'on-hold';
}
```

**Incase you want to know why?**
I'm using COD as a "quote request" feature. Products set to $0 are automatically registered as a "quote" not an "order". So when these COD orders come in, I want to be able to set and modify pricing before marking it as processing/awaiting-payment.

Comment: Duplicate questions are still duplicate, even if existing ones have out of date answers. When you have more reputation you can comment on and downvote out-of-date answers and offer [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to attract new answers to existing questions.

Comment: Okay. Well, in that case I don't think there is anything else I can do here. I'll just leave it for now then.