# Change order status for virtual, downloadable, free or backorder products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

i try to slightly modify with +1 check for plugin [located here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/handmade-woocommerce-order-status-control/#description)
So , for all Virtual Downloadable Free (price=0,00) & on Backorder products I want Woocommerce to set order status 'Processing'

the result I have with code below - Woocommerce to set order status 'Pending Payment'
Are there any ideas how to switch it to 'Processing':

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'handmade_woocommerce_order');

function handmade_woocommerce_order( $order_id ) 
{
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):
        $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); //get product id

    //get prodct settings i.e virtual
    $virtual_product = get_post_meta($product_id,'_virtual',true);
    $downloadable_product = get_post_meta($product_id,'_downloadable',true);
    $product_backordered=backorders_allowed($product_id,'_backorders',true);

    $price = get_post_meta($product_id,'_regular_price',true);

    $virtuald=get_option('hmade_vd');

    if($virtuald=='yes' && $downloadable_product=='yes' && $virtual_product=='yes' && $product_backordered=='yes')
    {
        if($price=='0.00')
        {
            $order->update_status( 'processing' );
        }

    }


endforeach;
}
```

Comment: This hook will not work for `$order->update_status()`, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45987434/11987538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note 1:** use `woocommerce_thankyou` hook instead

---

> **Note 2:** To know whether a product is virtual or downloadable you can use the following functions `$product->is_virtual();` and `$product->is_downloadable();` opposite `get_post_meta();`
>
> More info: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

---

> **Note 3:** It is better not to perform operations in a foreach loop, use a check afterwards

```php
function handmade_woocommerce_order( $order_id ) {
    if( ! $order_id ) return;

    // Get order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // get order items = each product in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Set variable
    $found = false;

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get product id
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );

        // Is virtual
        $is_virtual = $product->is_virtual();

        // Is_downloadable
        $is_downloadable = $product->is_downloadable();
        
        // Backorders allowed
        $backorders_allowed = $product->backorders_allowed();

        if( $is_virtual && $is_downloadable && $backorders_allowed ) {
            $found = true;
            // true, break loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // true
    if( $found ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'handmade_woocommerce_order', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Great example , thank you! The only thing need to be mentioned - `code`add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'handmade2_woocommerce_order', 10, 1 );`code` is still working in my version of code on site, because for Free products, "Thank you" page is not acceptable for me (it showing download links). Thanks anyway!