# WooCommerce auto complete orders with virtual products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

WooCommerce auto complete orders which has products marked as virtual & downloadable type.. while it puts orders into processing not complete status if its a virtual product only.

What if we need to auto complete orders with virtual products too instead of putting it in processing ?

We found this but it auto completes all orders not just the virtual products

```php
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

We need to auto complete the orders have virtual products as it happens for the orders with products marked as virtual & downlodable

Comment: Duplicate: [Change order status for virtual, downloadable, free or backorder products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61371178/change-order-status-for-virtual-downloadable-free-or-backorder-products-in-woo)

Comment: @7uc1f3r does that work only for free orders ?, i mean when the order total is 0 ?.. what we want is when order total is 0 & products in order is virtual then set the status to completed instead of processing .. is that the case ?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from further adapting the code to your wishes. 
In the end, not every answer you can find here is 100% what you are looking for, but this is the intention from SO, that you can learn from it. 
The example I share should definitely enable you to get the result you are looking for, therefore I see it as a duplicate question.

Comment: Yes  sir i got it .. but i just need to make sure that it works for free orders only not orders with payment methods right ?

Comment: You can always check for additional conditions such as `$order_total`. 
All information about obtaining order information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)