# Problem with automatic change of order status WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm having trouble with a function.

I want that after placing an order in the store, if the order value is zero, the order status will automatically change to completed.

Can anyone give a hint?

I'm using [Change order status for virtual, downloadable, free or backorder products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373278/11987538) answer code, but it's not quite what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us much about your problem. Still, there's a [woocommerce_checkout_order_created action](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-checkout.html#source-view.398) available to you.

A snippet like this may help you.

```php
function adam_check_order( $order ) {
    /* examine $order for the criterion you want, then call your function */
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_creation_action',  'adam_check_order' );
```

In general, the way you get this kind of stuff to work is

1. Install WordPress's [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin or some other way rapidly to edit and run code on your site.
2. Put your site into [WordPress debugging mode](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).
3. Look for a [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) or [Woocommerce hook](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html) (filter or action) that's invoked at the appropriate point in your workflow. Finding the correct hook can be challenging; they're not wonderfully documented. I use ctrl-f to search the web page listing the hooks. (If you use a filter hook be sure to return the filtered object passed to you.)
4. Write a snippet of code like my example.
5. Put [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) calls into your snippet. That will make php-ish stuff show up in your page when the hook is invoked, and show you the contents of the data objects (`$order` in your case) passed to you.
6. Get things working.
7. Remove the print_r() calls and take the site out  of debugging mode.