# setting custom order status in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I have followed [**this tutorial**](https://www.sellwithwp.com/woocommerce-custom-order-status-2/) and to add a custom order status "Awaiting Shipment":

My problem is I'm trying to update the status via a php function, but it stays sets on pending payment! So it is executing and changing the correct order but not with this new status.

My code:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order->update_status('Awaiting shipment', 'order_note');
```

I can set 'Awaiting Shipment' in the WordPress dashboard ok...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it using the slug `awaiting-shipment` instead, so your code will be:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$order->update_status('awaiting-shipment', 'order_note');
```

This time it will work…

> Also `'order_note'` *is optional* and should be replaced with a real explicit text as an order note should be.

To finish you also can use `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );`

Reference: [`WC_Order` `update_status()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.9.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L317-L350)

Related thread: [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_status_update' );

function my_custom_status_update( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'awaiting-shipment' );

}
```