# Exclude specific products on auto-complete orders process in Woocommerce

Tags: types, woocommerce, product, orders, payment-method

I’m currently using the code [from this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689563/3730754) to auto-complete orders so that new WooCommerce bookings are added to the calendar, (They only get added once marked as complete).

This works great for bookings, however, I’d like to exclude some other products from auto-completing.

Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "auto-complete order", bookings, and the calendar? Where do you check for products in this code?

Comment: Well, the code I was using doesn't and that's what I was trying to do. @LoicTheAztec's answer was exactly what I needed! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating through order items **is a heavier process**, than making a much more lighter SQL query.

Here is a custom conditional function that will check for products Ids in a Woocommerce Order (returning true or false):

```
function order_has_products( $order_id, $product_ids ){
    $product_ids = implode( "','", $product_ids );
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT COUNT(woim.meta_value) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE woi.order_id = $order_id AND woim.meta_key IN ('_product_id','_variation_id')
        AND woim.meta_value IN ('$product_ids')
    " );
    return $result > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Then you will use it in this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_auto_complete_order', 20, 1);
function wc_auto_complete_order($order_id){
    if (!$order_id)  return;

    // HERE define your Product Ids to exclude in the array 
    $product_ids = array( 37, 53 );

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    $found  = order_has_products( $order_id, $product_ids );

    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array('cod', 'cheque', '') ) || $found ) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        $order->update_status('completed');
    }

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

[WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)