# Auto complete processing orders based on their total amount in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to auto complete processing orders based on their total amount.

For the moment I have this code that is auto-completing all orders with processing status:

```
add_action( 'init', 'auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed' );
function auto_update_orders_status_from_processing_to_completed(){
    // Get all current "processing" customer orders
    $processing_orders = wc_get_orders( $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'wc-processing',
    ) );

    if(!empty($processing_orders))
        foreach($processing_orders as $order)
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
}
```

How can I make this code work **only for orders that have a total amount less than `$50`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `init` hook, you should try to use one of the following functions, that will auto-complete **processing** orders **that have a total amount less than $50** *(for example)*:

1) Using `woocommerce_order_status_processing` action hook *(the best choice)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total', 20, 4 );
function auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total( $order_id, $order ){
    // HERE define the max total order amount
    $max_total_limit = 50;

    if ( $order->get_total() < $max_total_limit ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) Using `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook *(good alternative if your orders are always in processing status)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total', 90, 1 );
function thankyou_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total( $order_id ){
    if( ! $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ){
        return;
    }

    // HERE define the max total order amount
    $max_total_limit = 50;

    if( $order->has_status('processing') && $order->get_total() < $max_total_limit ){
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### 3) Bulk update processing orders based on total amount *(2 possibilities)*:

**A) The lightest and efficient way with a direct SQL query** using `init` hook *(the best way)*:

```
add_action( 'init', 'sql_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total' );
function sql_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total(){
    // HERE define the max total order amount
    $max_total_limit = 50;

    global $wpdb;

    // Very light bulk update direct SQL query 
    $orders_ids = $wpdb->query("
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts as a
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
        SET a.post_status = 'wc-completed'
        WHERE a.post_status = 'wc-processing'
        AND b.meta_key = '_order_total' AND b.meta_value < '$max_total_limit'
    ");
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

**B) Based on your code** using `init` hook *(**Very heavy**, but more compatible with future database structure changes in woocommerce, if it happen one day)*:

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_thankyou_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total' );
function init_thankyou_auto_complete_processing_orders_based_on_total(){
    // HERE define the max total order amount
    $max_total_limit = 50;

    // Get all processing orders
    $orders = wc_get_orders( array( 'limit' => -1, 'status' => 'processing') );

    if( sizeof($orders) > 0 ) {
        // loop through processing orders
        foreach(  $orders as $order ) {
            if( $order->get_total() < $max_total_limit ) {
                $order->update_status( 'completed' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)