# Automark ONLY Paid orders to "Completed" status in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, payment-method

I would like to automark just success paid orders to "Completed" status. I have searched a lot on Stack and Google, and found this answer code:
[WooCommerce: Auto complete paid Orders (depending on Payment methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders-depending-on-payment-methods/35689563#35689563)

But problem is that the code mark all placed orders to "Completed" status not depending if order was success placed or not.

What do I need to change in the code to automark ONLY Paid orders to "Completed" status?

Answer (score 3):

**New enhanced and simplified code version** *replacement* (March 2019):

See: [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563)

---

**Original answer:**

For Paypal and other third party gateways, the "paid" order status to target is "processing" *(and "completed")*, so you can lightly change the code to:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 20, 1 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! $order_id )
        return;

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // No updated status for orders delivered with Bank wire, Cash on delivery and Cheque payment methods.
    if ( in_array( $order->get_payment_method(), array( 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque', '' ) ) ) {
        return;
    // Updated status to "completed" for paid Orders with all others payment methods
    } elseif ( in_array( $order->get_status(), array('on-hold', 'processing') ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> This way you will avoid "failed", "Cancelled" or "Pending" orders.

Comment: When add your latest code get Error:

`} elseif ( in_array( $order->get_status(), array('on-hold', 'processing') ) {`

Also when have non success payment order stuck at pending payment , and should be Canceled i think.

Comment: @DorotiHenridgz Sorry but this code works… The code line at the end is just suggested for testing and should replace the existing elseif statement line.