# Woocommerce Gateway default order status customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I've used the following code which works fine, it makes all orders default status to be on hold.

```
/**
 * Auto Complete all WooCommerce orders.
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );
}
```

But I need to combine this with shipping/billing address. i.e. execute this code *Only* if the order's shipping or billing address is NOT UK or France. Customers from all other countries will be placed on hold as per this code, while UK & France orders get the default order status set by the payment geteway's settings.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to exclude France and UK billing and shipping countries:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'country_based_auto_on_hold_orders' );
function country_based_auto_on_hold_orders( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( ! ( in_array( $order->get_billing_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) || in_array( $order->get_shipping_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) ) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'on-hold' );
    }
}
```

Now using `woocommerce_thankyou` hook, **is the old way**. To **avoid multiple email notifications** on status changes, use the following instead:

For **all payment gateways** except Cash on delivery (COD):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_on_old_paid_order', 10, 3 );
function wc_auto_on_old_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    if ( ! ( in_array( $order->get_billing_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) || in_array( $order->get_shipping_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) ) ) {
        $status = 'on-hold'
    }
    return $status;
}
```

For **Cash on delivery** (COD) payments:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_cod_order', 10, 2 );
function wc_auto_complete_cod_order( $status, $order ) {
    if ( ! ( in_array( $order->get_billing_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) || in_array( $order->get_shipping_country(), ['UK', 'FR'] ) ) ) {
        $status = 'on-hold'
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Related: [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563)

Comment: Thank you so much!