# Auto change order status to completed for specific products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have a virtual product and I want it to change status after payment is completed.
The following code changes all purchases to "completed", but I want to change only one of my products, not all of them.
My product is a variable product and has 4 items,

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
    function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
            $order->update_status( 'completed' );
        }
    }
```

I searched a lot but did not find an answer. please help me. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target specific product(s) Id(s) from order items, to make your code work only for them as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    $product_ids   = array('23'); // Here set your targeted product(s) Id(s)
    $product_found = false;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
            $product_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) && $product_found ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

If you want to target those products **exclusively**, then you will use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order' );
function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_order( $order_id ) { 
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    $product_ids   = array('23'); // Here set your targeted product(s) Id(s)
    $product_found = true;
    
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( ! array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
            $product_found = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) && $product_found ) {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should  works.

---

> #### Addition: Avoid multiple notifications
>
> You should better use `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` hook instead like in *[WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563)* answer, to avoid multiple notifications.
>
> So the code is going to be:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 3 );
> function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
>     $product_ids   = array('23'); // Here set your targeted product(s) Id(s)
>     $product_found = false;
>     
>     // Loop through order items
>     foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
>         if( array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
>             $product_found = true;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return $product_found ? 'completed' : $status;
> }
> ```
>
> Or targeting products **exclusively**:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 3 );
> function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
>     $product_ids   = array('23'); // Here set your targeted product(s) Id(s)
>     $product_found = true;
>     
>     // Loop through order items
>     foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
>         if( ! array_intersect( $product_ids, array($item->get_product_id(), $item->get_variation_id()) ) ) {
>             $product_found = false;
>             break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return $product_found ? 'completed' : $status;
> }
> ```
>
> It should work...

Comment: also, I just need to send an email notification for the product I mentioned above.
Because the "Processing" and "Completed" notifications are sent at the same time.
(I want to apply these settings to only one product, not all products)
I did not find an answer to this in your suggested article,
thank you for your attention.

Comment: @matin I have added some code with `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` hook…

Comment: I used both codes together and it worked fine. Thanks for the quick reply my friend