# Set order status to "Processing" after payment for a single virtual product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, virtual, status

In WooCommerce, any virtual product order status is automatically marked as "Completed" after payment.

I need the status to be set to "Processing" after payment. This behavior should apply only to a single virtual product ID that I specify.

The closest solution that I found, for I'm looking for, is this:

[Auto change order status to completed for specific products in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65544274/auto-change-order-status-to-completed-for-specific-products-in-woocommerce)

The only issue is that it sets the status to "Completed" instead of "Processing", and I need it the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function virtual_product_woocommerce_order_status( $order_id ) {
    if( ! $order_id ) return;


    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_items = $order->get_items();

    $is_virtual_found = false;
    $order_product_ids = array();
    $specific_product_id = 1342;

    foreach ( $order_items as $item ) {
        
        // Get product id
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        
        // Add the product IDS to the list
        $order_product_ids[] = $item['product_id'];
        // Is virtual
        $is_virtual = $product->is_virtual();

        // Is_downloadable
        $is_downloadable = $product->is_downloadable();
        
        // Backorders allowed
        $backorders_allowed = $product->backorders_allowed();

        if( $is_virtual && $is_downloadable && $backorders_allowed ) {
            $is_virtual_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // true
    if( $is_virtaul_found && in_array($specific_product_id, $order_product_ids) ) {
        $order->update_status( 'processing' );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'virtual_product_woocommerce_order_status', 10, 1 );
```