# Why does the order get Processing status (when paying for product using a coupon)?

Tags: woocommerce

Please help figure it out. Some strange behavior in the payment process. If the buyer makes a purchase without using the coupon code, if the payment is successful, it is immediately transferred to the status: completed(it's important). But as soon as the buyer makes a purchase using the coupon. Even with successful payment, the order is transferred to the status: Processing.

I tried to use this code:

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order', 20 );
  function custom_woocommerce_auto_complete_paid_order( $order_id ) {
  if ( ! $order_id )
     return;
     $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) ) {
    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }else {
    return;
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyway, when paying for an item using a coupon, it first gets into the status Processing. Please, help me figure it out.

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563, may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks a lot I'm checking now, hope it's can help to solve my trouble.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes, it's amazing working on our project. Thanks a lot!

Comment: happy that it helped you…