# WooCommerce Virtual products - Autocomplete orders after payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, status

I have virtual products and I would like them to be auto-completed when purchased.

I found the code pasted below, added it to functions.php, and it did work, BUT with one caveat: 
When people choose to pay by bank transfer (yep, they still do...), the order is set to on hold (OR maybe Pending payment, not sure, the developer set it up in Italian). In these cases the order should be manually updated when the payment is received and only then it can be completed.

However the code below sets every order as complete when the user lands on the Thank you page, that obviously doesn't work in these cases.

Any ideas?
How can I solve this?

My code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'wpd_autocomplete_virtual_orders', 10, 1 );
function wpd_autocomplete_virtual_orders( $order_id ) {
  
    if( ! $order_id ) return;
  
    // Get order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  
    // get order items = each product in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();
  
    // Set variable
    $only_virtual = true;
  
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
          
        // Get product object
        if ( isset($item['variation_id']) && ! empty($item['variation_id']) ) {
 
            $product = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] );
 
        } else {
 
            $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
 
        }
 
        // Safety check
        if ( ! is_object($product) ) {
 
            return false;
 
        }
                 
        // Is virtual
        $is_virtual = $product->is_virtual();
  
        // Is_downloadable
        $is_downloadable = $product->is_downloadable();
  
        if ( ! $is_virtual && ! $is_downloadable  ) {
  
            $only_virtual = false;
  
        }
  
    }
  
    // true
    if ( $only_virtual ) {
  
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
  
    }
 
}
```

In short: I tried to use some code, it didn't work as expected. I'd be grateful if you could advise on how to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [WooCommerce: Auto complete paid orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686707/woocommerce-auto-complete-paid-orders/35689563#35689563), try the following instead that will autocomplete paid orders if all items are virtual *(but no bank transfer orders)*:

```php
// Conditional function that check if order items are all virtual
function only_virtual_order_items( $order ) {
    $only_virtual_items = true; // Initializing

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        // Check if there are items that are not virtual
        if ( ! ( $product->is_virtual() || $product->is_downloadable() ) ) {
            $only_virtual_items = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $only_virtual_items;
}

// Autocomplete paid orders
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_paid_order', 10, 3 );
function wc_auto_complete_paid_order( $status, $order_id, $order ) {
    // Check if all items are virtual
    if ( only_virtual_order_items( $order ) ) {
        $status = 'completed'; 
    }
    return $status;
}
```

If you want to autocomplete COD (Cash On Delivery Orders) use the following too:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cod_process_payment_order_status', 'wc_auto_complete_cod_order', 10, 2 );
function wc_auto_complete_cod_order( $status, $order ) {
    // Check if all items are virtual
    if ( only_virtual_order_items( $order ) ) {
        $status = 'completed'; 
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much Loic, it does indeed work! In the meantime a new problem emerged (I think unrelated, ut not sure): orders placed on the italian version of the shop appear in dashboard, but those placed on the english version do not appear in dashboard and I can't retrieve them in any way. The dashboard would show me that there are 5 orders "processing" but then would list only 3, the 2 missing were placed for the english shop- i know because i placed them for testing. Any idea if the two things are related or how to fix this? I'm using Polylang Pro. Thanks, Letizia